# Issue with Thai character rendering

Tags: java, thymeleaf, itext7

When i use itext to render Thai characters in PDF generation from a HTML file with thymeleaf, there are issues with some characters. Whenever there are 3 characters at the same horizontal position like this: "ชื่" the top most character is pushed down and merged with the 2nd  character.

Correct text when opened as HTML file:
[image: Correct text]

Incorrect text after opening the generated PDF file:
[image: Incorrect text]

Is there anyway to fix this?

```
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("productName", "product1");

String html = templateEngine.process(htmtFilePath, context);

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
ITextFontResolver resolver = renderer.getFontResolver();

resolver.addFont(new ClassPathResource(FONT_PATH_EKACHON_BOLD).getPath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
renderer.layout();

String fileName = "output.pdf"
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code you use to render the text in iText. If possible provide a short self-contained example that we can run.

Comment: you need [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph) to render Thai characters correctly